# onmouseover show div adjusting x and y

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning, onmouseover

I have several small images in my page and onmouseover I show a div next to the image. So far so good. However when the image is on the bottom of the page I'd like to diplay the div not under the image but above. Basically what I'm trying to do is to verify where the image is and if is near the bottom I show the div above the image instead. The same thing if the image is to close to the right margin to show the div on the left.

Do anyone know any simple way of achieving this?

Cheers

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: There's always a simple way, but also 1000s of ways to achieve it. It all depends on the markup you use. so without seeing what you have, don't expect any useful codewise answer. Theoretically expect 100s :)

Comment: Ok.Lets see... I need to create this dynamically so I have  sb.Append("<div class=\"marker\" id=\"marker" + markerCount + "\" style=\"left:" + mark.x + "px;top:" + mark.y + "px;\" onmouseover=\"document.getElementById('div" + markerCount + "').style.visibility = 'visible'\">");
 sb.Append("<img src=\"~/images/hotSpot.png\" alt=\"Hot Spot\" />");
sb.Append("</div>"); As you may notice I already have the x and y position. #divmarker + count is the div that I want to show. Tks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code, it's a bit hard to suggest the "right" way to do it, but I'd try the following method (using JQuery syntax):

First, calculate your 'threshold' - whatever is the lowest point you want the `div` to appear underneath. Probably the easiest way to do this is with `$(document).height()` and subtract X pixels.

Then, on hover, calculate where the image is on the page. You can do this with `.offset();`.

If the top of the image is higher than the threshold, show the `div` below, otherwise show the `div` above.

Note: Depending on how your page is set up you could calculate the positions of each one on load and then apply a class to the ones below the threshold, and use that to position the corresponding `div` correctly.

Comment: I understand your approach... the div height is unknown but I'll try I then I'll let you know. How this works with width? Should I get $(document).width/2 and if image x position is bigger I'll show to the left and vice versa? Another issue is that I'm doing this in code behind so I dont know an "good" way to get the $(document).height